# How to declare typing for a dictionary with multiple but specified value types in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

I have a method which create a dictionary with 3 values where the key is always a `str` but the objects for the values of each key are of a different type for example I would like to declare something like this (obviously this is not correct:

```
Dict[str,ObjectType1,str,ObjectType2,str,List[ObjectType3]]
```

*Note* I don't want to use `Union` for the three value types because I want to ensure that the returned dictionary has exactly this structure

Comment: What's wrong with `Dict[str, Union[ObjectType1, ...]]`?!

Comment: union implies each value can belong to any of these types. I want to specify that I will have exactly one of these types only once.

Comment: You're saying your dict will have exactly one `ObjectType1`, exactly one `ObjectType2` and exactly one `List[ObjectType3]`, but you don't know the keys?

Comment: @deceze yes as you said the types of the values are known, the keys are not

Comment: Then you will still have to figure out in code which is which, meaning any key could store any value, so a `Union` is just about good enough. I don't think you can express "must contain these three types in total" with a type hint.

Comment: @deceze mm ok I ll find a workaround if this is how it is

Comment: You can't define type like this, Python was not designed to support types originally, and type hinting is basically just an addon. You will have to check each type as you receive it. You see these types of type guards in a lot of code that can handle multiple type `str`, path like, `bytes`, etc but must be handles or might need some preprocessing before continuing work

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with typing...
But you may use NamedTuple in this case if you want to keep strict type notation
E.g. something like this:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple


class MyCustomType(NamedTuple):
    type1: ObjectType1
    type2: ObjectType1
    type3: List[ObjectType3]


def func() -> MyCustomType:
    data = {}
    ...
    return MyCustomType(**data)
```

Comment: hello thanks for the reply. Yes but the keys could change in my case. A named tuple implies that I know the keys and they are fixed no?

Comment: the would be fixed, but at least you'll now how to access each type. You could store each type with the key something like `type1: tuple[str, ObjetType1]`. Or store the key with the associated type and access the value with those two mappings

Answer (score 0):

Python was not designed for strong typing like this. The best way is to probably define the values them as a [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union):

```py
dict[str, Union[ObjectType1,. ObjectType2, list[ObjectType3]]
```

When you access them you'll have to check their type:

```
value = d[key]

if isinstance(value, ObjectType1):
    pass
elif isinstance(value, ObjectType2):
    pass
elif isinstance(value, list):
    pass
else:
    raise TypeError(f"unhandled type: {type(value)}")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes I know I can use Union like this but I was looking for a build in way to declare this (if it exists)

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a builtin way :( Any workaround is going to be just as annoying to use

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is not doing what I wanted to initially but by the discussion started thanks to the other replies and comments I realized that the `dict` I was using was not a good structure for what I wanted, since there is no build in support for this strong typing.

So since I wanted to ensure that I always get back an object with tree elements each of which is of a specific type I changed my data structure to a simple `tuple` :

```
Tuple[Tuple[str,str,str],Tuple[ObjectType1,ObjectType2,List[ObjectType3]]
```

this allows me to use the type checking exactly as I wanted. I store the keys in the first tuple, in order, and the values in the second tuple, in order again, and with type checking. Not ideal but it is a workaround.

This could also work:

```
Tuple[Tuple[str,ObjectType1],Tuple[str,ObjectType2], Tuple[str,List[ObjectType3]]]
```

*Note* (named tuple suggested in another response would work if someone wanted to have fixed keys, but I didnt want that in my case)